# Data Studio Time Series cutting of X axis (too many data points)

Tags: looker-studio

Working on a time series graph in data studio, and it seems whenever 3 years are chosen (2016-2019), the graph shifts left to show from the initial and only goes up to 2018.

Aggregation on the weekly level is showing fine, however, daily is causing this issue. Even playing around with x axis styling isn't sufficient.

I have 2 line series and a bar series.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looked like the bar series was taking too much space visually. After changing it to a line series, it is working fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected / actual output. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a whether this did resolve the specific issue faced or was it due to another chart setting...